# How do you read and write http headers in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, http-headers

Is it even possible to both read and write http headers in actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... ok setting them doesn't seem to be a problem.

Pretty straight forward, you just add and array of URLRequestHeader objects to the URLRequest object.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var someheader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader( "Connection", "OK" );
req.requestHeaders = [someheader];
```

However, you can't read them in the regular FlashPlayer. This can be done in AIR and Flash Lite on using the requestHeader property on the HTTPStatusEvent.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatus);

private function onStatus( e:HTTPStatusEvent ) : void
{
    var headers:Array = e.requestHeaders; // only available in FlashLite and AIR  
}
```

This is kinda weird.